# how to call a method in a class without this object in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi friends I'm making an app which lists users's emails via Gmail API. For this I have a method which lists threads from user account and then messages in that threads gets fetched. My function is as below:

```
   public listThreads(opt_params){
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function(){

        let request = gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.list({
            'userId': 'me',
            'q': opt_params
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {

            $.each(response.threads,  function() {

               let thread_id = this.id;

               this.getThread(thread_id, this.process_thread);
// error appears on above line. which says "this.getThread is not a function" 
            });
        });
});
    }
```

Error is "this.getThread is not a function". And that is because "this" now refers to response object and it does not refers to class members anymore. But I need to call getThread function. So I need to know if there is any other way to call class functions without this keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a typescript method without using `this`

Instead you should use fat `arrow operators (=>)` at three places in your code as opposed to `function`, to retain the context of `this`.

1. parameter of `gapi.client.load()`

   ```
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', () => {
             ......
    });
   ```
2. parameter of `request.execute()`

   ```
   request.execute((response) => {
          ....
   })
   ```
3. parameter of $.each

   ```
   $.each(response.threads, () => {
          let thread_id = this.id;

          this.getThread(thread_id, this.process_thread);
          // this should be accessible here
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks Buddy! but i have to do slightly changes in your proposed solution to make it work. that is in 3rd portion I passed parameter `thread` and then got `thread_id` like this `let thread_id = thread.id;` .. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the context, `this` is lost in the callback. Use arrow functions in typescript to preserve the context!

`request.execute().then((response)=> {
// here you will have access to 'this'
})`

Comment: now it is saying `this.zone` is undefined.  obviously "this" object gets updated and now it does not refer to any of class member or method anymore.

Comment: sorry I forgot to do `that=this;` check the edited version

Comment: initialize it before calling `(request.execute)` function

Comment: really appreciate your efforts for my code. But now it is saying "that is not defined" and this is because `request.execute` returns result in a callback and `that` is not accessible in that callback scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176246/discussion-between-sujay-and-asad-ullah).